# How to parse below ajax response in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

{"{\"3\":\"Dubai\",\"2\":\"Ajman\",\"1\":\"Abu Dhabi\",\"7\":\"Umm al-Quwain\",\"6\":\"Sharjah\",\"5\":\"Ras al-Khaimah\",\"4\":\"Fujairah\"}":"{\"3\":\"Dubai\",\"2\":\"Ajman\",\"1\":\"Abu Dhabi\",\"7\":\"Umm al-Quwain\",\"6\":\"Sharjah\",\"5\":\"Ras al-Khaimah\",\"4\":\"Fujairah\"}","{\"17\":\"Thai\",\"18\":\"Korean\",\"15\":\"Traditional Chinese\",\"16\":\"Simplified Chinese\",\"14\":\"English (Asia)\"}":"{\"17\":\"Thai\",\"18\":\"Korean\",\"15\":\"Traditional Chinese\",\"16\":\"Simplified Chinese\",\"14\":\"English (Asia)\"}"}

Comment: Wow, what is this being serialized by?

Comment: Indeed, what is the response supposed to be? Is it supposed to be an array of some kind?

Comment: (1) It seems your double-quotes are being escaped an extra time. (2) Please post the code that you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you exactly want the parsed result to look, but here goes:

```
var raw = '{"{\"3\":\"Dubai\",\"2\":\"Ajman\",\"1\":\"Abu Dhabi\",\"7\":\"Umm al-Quwain\",\"6\":\"Sharjah\",\"5\":\"Ras al-Khaimah\",\"4\":\"Fujairah\"}":"{\"3\":\"Dubai\",\"2\":\"Ajman\",\"1\":\"Abu Dhabi\",\"7\":\"Umm al-Quwain\",\"6\":\"Sharjah\",\"5\":\"Ras al-Khaimah\",\"4\":\"Fujairah\"}","{\"17\":\"Thai\",\"18\":\"Korean\",\"15\":\"Traditional Chinese\",\"16\":\"Simplified Chinese\",\"14\":\"English (Asia)\"}":"{\"17\":\"Thai\",\"18\":\"Korean\",\"15\":\"Traditional Chinese\",\"16\":\"Simplified Chinese\",\"14\":\"English (Asia)\"}"}';

var re = /\"(\d+)\":\"(.*?)\"/g,
    matches = [],
    match;

while(match = re.exec(raw)) {
    matches.push(match);
}

var parsed = matches.reduce(function(result, cur) {
    result[cur[1]] = cur[2];
}, {});

console.log(parsed);

> Object {1: "Abu Dhabi", 2: "Ajman", 3: "Dubai", 4: "Fujairah", 5: "Ras al-Khaimah", 6: "Sharjah", 7: "Umm al-Quwain", 14: "English (Asia)", 15: "Traditional Chinese", 16: "Simplified Chinese", 17: "Thai", 18: "Korean"}
```

Alternatively, if you're wanting these parsed into an array, change the reducer to this:

```
var parsed = matches.reduce(function(result, cur) {
    result[cur[1] - 1] = cur[2];
    return result;
}, []);

console.log(parsed);

> ["Abu Dhabi", "Ajman", "Dubai", "Fujairah", "Ras al-Khaimah", "Sharjah", "Umm al-Quwain", undefined × 6, "English (Asia)", "Traditional Chinese", "Simplified Chinese", "Thai", "Korean"]
```